# VIM - ctags support for cucumber/gherkin

Tags: vim, cucumber, ctags, gherkin

Is there a way, in VIM, to navigate to a Cucumber step definition from a .feature file? I was hoping the exuberant-ctags library would have support, but I haven't figured it out yet. Anyone have experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not used it fully, but had a bit of luck with this vim script:- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2973